# Is there a way to skip a data when a domain doesn't contain a specific variable

Tags: python, arrays, list, jupyter, whois

I'm really confused on how to bypass this problem from whois, is there a way so that when whois outputs the domain variable and it doesn't contain the specific variable that i want to showcase, it would just skip it instead of giving me an error?

[image: Contains Emails in array]

And below does not contain any web variable when whois outputs.
[image: Does not contain emails]

This is the error that i got when inside the array list doesn't contain any emails variables.

```
Cell In [419], line 4, in whodata(host)
      2 res = whois.whois(host)
      3 print(res['registrar'])
----> 4 print(res['emails'])
      5 print(res['country'])
      6 print("---------")

KeyError: 'emails'
```

```
import whois

def whodata(host):
    res = whois.whois(host)
    print(res['registrar'])
    print(res['emails'])
    print(res['country'])
    print("---------")
    
test = ["minecraft.net", "google.com",'mob1lebn1-co.id.co.id']

for host in test:
    whodata(host)
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

You can use an if-else condition or ternary operator to check whether the dictionary contains the given key or not.

```py
import whois

def whodata(host):
    res = whois.whois(host)
    print(res['registrar'])
    print(res['emails'] if 'emails' in res else '')
    print(res['country'])
    print("---------")
    
test = ["minecraft.net", "google.com",'mob1lebn1-co.id.co.id']

for host in test:
    whodata(host)
```